# CSS Percentage Widths Jiggling Around

Tags: css, alignment, width, shake

I'm having an issue with percent width elements in any browser. If you look at this jsfiddle and slowly resize the browser you'll see right hand side of the bottom row jiggles.

http://jsfiddle.net/drAWc/

HTML:

```
<div class='main'>
    <section class='full'>
        <div>1_1</div>
    </section>
    <section class='half'>
        <div>1_2</div>
    </section>
    <section class='half'>
        <div>1_2</div>
    </section>
    <section class='third'>
        <div>1_3</div>
    </section>
    <section class='third'>
        <div>1_3</div>
    </section>
    <section class='third'>
        <div>1_3</div>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div {
    width: auto;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
.full {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.third {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
}
.half {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

I understand that three widths of 33.333% would add up to a total of 99.999% - but setting the `.full` element to 99.999% causes the half width ones to work (as that row's width totals 100%).

Is there a solution to this, or is it just the nature of things?

The only workaround I can think of would be something like.. setting every third `.third` div as width:33.334% which is a bit insane.

Comment: Percentages are by their nature not exact, so it's going to display differently at different browser sizes - though other than you testing how it looks on different browser sizes, I can't see many people resizing their browser in this style - most will keep it to one size, probably maximized.

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/drAWc/2/

```
.main { width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; }
div { width: auto; background: blue; text-align: center; }

.full { float: left; width: 100%; }
.third { float: left; width: 33.33%; }
.half { float: left; width: 50%; }
```

will not jiggle.

I have set the `width: 100%;` for the main div

Comment: On Firefox 17 it jiggles!

Answer (score 0):

I would give one of the three div's a widht of 33.4%. The difference is so small that you won't see it, but it fixes the jiggle.

```
.third:first-child { width: 33.4%; }
```

But it somehow doesn't (check http://jsfiddle.net/drAWc/1/).

When the code is added as an inline-style to the first `.third` it works (check http://jsfiddle.net/drAWc/3/):

```
<section class='third' style='width: 33.4%;'><div>1_3</div></section>
```